# Regex pattern to find force unwrapped variables

Tags: swift

I want to find all the force unwrapped variables in my Xcode project. For example anything that's similar to:

```
variableName!.property
```

or

```
variableName!,
```

or

```
variableName! : otherVariable
```

or

```
variableName!)
```

Or any other similar occurrences of force unwrapped variables. What would be a regex pattern for that that I can use in the Xcode search?

Comment: I don't think there's any regex pattern that 100% satisfies your needs. If you require that level of precision (i.e. you are writing an automatic tool), you need to delve into the [Clang Abstract Syntax Tree](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one will search for only valid variable names (alphanumeric strings starting with a letter) that are followed by an `!` which is then followed by a space, tab, newline, or a period, comma, colon, or closing parenthesis . This search also excludes finding instances of `try!` and `as!`.

`([A-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*(?<![(try)(as)])![.,:)\n\t\r ])`

This next pattern will match `try!` and `as!` if you are interested in finding those as well.

`([A-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*![.,:)\n\t\r ])`

It should be noted both of these patterns will also match for variable types that are force unwrapped optionals (a common variable to be force unwrapped being `@IBOutlet`s)

A really good resource for writing and testing regular expressions is [regexr.com](http://regexr.com)

Comment: I used this, but took out the new line character. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Not fool-proof (that would require a full reading of the Swift syntax) but good enough for most cases:

```
\w[\w\d]*!
```

Of course you can simply search for `!` - there are only a couple uses other than force unwrap: negative test (`!=`) and boolean (`!valid`). You may scoop up some string literals in the search, but unless you are writing an automatic tool, it hardly matters.

Comment: ! is also used for inequality and testing booleans

Answer (score 0):

You should search `.+!(\.|,| :|\))` using the Find > Regular Expression tool

Comment: This will also bring up properties at the init stage that have been declared as unwrapped, like `fileprivate var button: UIButton!`, which I don't want.

Comment: so you just want match the 4 previous cases ?

Comment: The 4 cases, plus any other similar ones (if I've forgotten any) that doesn't include the one I just mentioned.